# set value from axios get outside

Tags: node.js, typescript

how can I set up value from axios.get method outside?
I use TypeScript and I have not found any solution that works.

```
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';

async function data() {
    return await axios.get('https://myUrl/api/v4/3131', {
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Basic auth'
    }
  }).then(response => { return response.data})
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
} 

var data = data();
console.log(response)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this function returns a promise as is, so you'll have to add `.then()` and `.catch`.

```js
data()
.then(data => {
  console.log(data)
})
.catch(err => {
  // Do whatever you want
  alert(err)
})
```